# Nginx: Trying to match all urls with foo in them.

Tags: regex, nginx

I am trying to match these so that they are proxied to another url. There will always to something after but, not always something before.

1. www.xyz.com/foo/ -> www.abc.com/foo/
2. www.xyz.com/bar-foo/ -> www.abc.com/bar-foo/
3. www.xyz.com/bar-foo-this/ -> www.abc.com/bar-foo-this/

I know I could use a new rule for each case but, I trying to find a generic way if possible.

I have this right now :

```
location ^~ /([^/]*foo[^/]+)/ {     
    proxy_pass https://localhost:8080/$1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got this regex:

```
([^\/]*foo[^\/]*)
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aZ2oD9/1)</kbd>

#### Explaination:

```
1st Capturing group ([^\/]*foo[^\/]*)
    [^\/]* match a single character not present in the list below
        Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        \/ matches the character / literally
    foo matches the characters foo literally (case sensitive)
    [^\/]* match a single character not present in the list below
        Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        \/ matches the character / literally
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```